# Concatenation/creation of symbolic expressions/statements

Tags: python, theano

I want to create something like this programmatically:

```
a = (_vec, T.set_subtensor(_vec[0], _init[0]))[1]
b = (a,    T.set_subtensor(   a[1], a[0] * 2))[1]
c = (b,    T.set_subtensor(   b[2], b[1] * 2))[1]

vec_update  = (c, T.set_subtensor(c[3], c[2] * 2))

test_vector = function([], outputs=vec_update)

subt = test_vector()
```

We got `a = (_vec, T.set_subtensor(_vec[0], _init[0]))[1]` so a is that whole statement. This is not doing anything yet. Then there is `b = (a, T.set_subtensor( a[1], a[0] * 2))[1]` which is depending on `a` and is another statement itself.This goes on until `vec_update`. I know it looks ugly but it just updates the column of a vector like `col[n] = col[n-1] * 2` for `col[0] = 1` returning a vector looking like this:

```
[[   1.    2.    4. ...,   32.   64.  128.]]
```

Now Imagine I would want to do this a thousand times.. therefore I am wondering if I could generate such statements since they follow an easy pattern.

These "*concatenated*" statements are not evaluated until

```
test_vector = function([], outputs=vec_update)
```

which is when they are getting compiled to `CUDA-code` and

```
subt = test_vector()
```

does execute everything.

Comment: If you want to build a string, it's easy. If you want to evaluate an expression using a loop, that's even easier. What are you after, actually?

Comment: Have a look at [infix notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation), then give it a try with [`infix`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/infix/).

Comment: @LevLevitsky Not after a string in particular. I was just wondering if I can concatenate such expressions any maybe even build them up recursively (see edit).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Hmm I am not sure if that does what I am looking for. I'll keep searching.

Comment: That's not an expression, that is a statement (call statement). Please be specific as to what you need. The two things are very different. Maybe you can describe the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Sorry, the Theano documentation always speaks of "symbolic expressions" that getting evaluated and compiled. I added some additional information - I hope this makes is more clear what I am meaning.

Comment: It's not clear what you really need, because your example looks like the kind of thing that can be handled with ordinary Python functions. For example, define a function or lambda that can add numbers: `add = lambda x, y: x + y`. And then your loop can be written in an ordinary way: `for i in range(0, 2): e = add(e, a - b)`. Perhaps your goal to define expressions that will be evaluated **later**, rather than eagerly?

Comment: @FMc Well yes. The reason why I have to "build" those statements first is that that statement is going to be compiled to `CUDA` code and later executed on the GPU. This is the reason why I can't do it just in a `for` loop like you are suggesting. My varaibles are very large matrices and I want e.g. pretend as if a specific function gets called many times by just build the execution graph programitcally first for compilation and later execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function nesting:

```
def nest(f, g):
    def h(x):
        return f(g(x), x)
    return h

expr = lambda (a,b) : a
expr = nest((lambda x, (a, b): x + (a - b)), expr)
expr = nest((lambda x, (a, b): x + (a - b)), expr)

print expr((1,2)) # prints -1
```

Regarding the example code, you could do something like (modifying `nest` to use no arguments):

```
def nest(f, g):
    def h():
        return f(g())
    return h

expr = lambda: (_vec, _init)[1]
expr = nest(lambda x: T.set_subtensor(x[1], x[0] * 2)[1], expr)
expr = nest(lambda x: T.set_subtensor(x[2], x[1] * 2)[1], expr)
expr = nest(lambda x: T.set_subtensor(x[3], x[2] * 2)[1], expr)
expr = nest(lambda x: T.set_subtensor(x[4], x[3] * 2)[1], expr)

test_vector = function([], outputs=expr)
subt = test_vector()
```

Comment: Hi! That looks promising - could you take a short look at my edit? The last code-block before **Additional Information** where `vec_update` is defined. Is such a statement produceable with that?

Comment: Sorry, I saw your edit but didn't understand what you are trying to do... Could you clarify?

Comment: Well we got `a = (_vec, T.set_subtensor(_vec[0], _init[0]))[1]` so `a` is that whole statement. This is not doing anything yet. Then there is `b = (a,    T.set_subtensor(   a[1], a[0] * 2))[1]` which is dependend on `a` and is another statement itself.This goes on until `vec_update`. I know it looks ugly but it just updates the column of a vector like `col[n] = col[n-1] * 2` for `col[0] = 1`. Now Imagine I would want to do this a thousand times.. therefore I am wondering if I could *generate* such statements since they follow an easy pattern.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a possible solution... As you can see, the "x" argument in the function equals to the evaluation of the previous function (that we're nesting over), so I think this could help you do what you're trying to do... You can then use a loop to nest the functions in a more programmatic way.

Comment: This was totally what I was looking for! It seems like that the framework does not accept these lambda functions just right on but this brought me further. Thanks :)